# Youtube video in <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, object, youtube

I have simple problem with my youtube video in  tag:

```
<object src="https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8" width="300" height="300"></object>
```

After that I have an blank HTML element. Do anybody know why?

Comment: why not using `<canvas>` ?

Comment: How to use <canvas> on yt videos?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `iframe`

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the "data" parameter instead of the "src" to specify the link:

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=Bey4XXJAqS8" width="300" height="300"></object>
```

Comment: Still the same, i've changed src to data and still have blank html element ;(

Answer (score 0):

Hi use data like this For reference [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<object width="400" height="400" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7_Aqn-ooYyw">
</object>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing `src` to `data` doesn't work, you could try to change from `<object>` to `<iframe>`. 
I used this for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

I know this too late for answering, but I hope this can help future same question.

you can try:

1. Replace `watch?v=` with `embed/`
2. Use `data` than `src`

and this the full example:

the real url is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w`
you can try like this:

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XqZsoesa55w" />
```